# How do I trim zeros at the end of a custom ReadOnlySequence implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, sequence

The web socket server expects JSON strings. `_webSocket.SendAsync` sends `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>`. The issue is that `sequence.First` has trailing zeros. It results in an invalid JSON message because of the trailing zeros. The question is how do I trim them?

### Usage

```cs
var request = new JsonRpcRequest<object>
{
    JsonRpc = "2.0",
    Id = 1,
    Method = "public/get_instruments",
    Params = @params
};

var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

using var buffer = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(message));
Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder().Convert(message, buffer.Memory.Span, true, out _, out _, out _);

var seq = new OwnedMemorySequence<byte>();
seq.Append(buffer);

var msg = new ChannelWebSocket.Message
{
    MessageType = WebSocketMessageType.Text,
    Payload = seq
};

await client.Output.WriteAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

### Code

```cs
private async Task OutputLoopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await foreach (var message in _output.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        var sequence = message.Payload.ReadOnlySequence;
        if (sequence.IsEmpty)
            continue;

        while (!sequence.IsSingleSegment)
        {
            await _webSocket.SendAsync(sequence.First, message.MessageType, false, cancellationToken);
            sequence = sequence.Slice(sequence.First.Length);
        }

        await _webSocket.SendAsync(sequence.First, message.MessageType, true, cancellationToken);
        message.Payload.Dispose();
    }

    await _webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, cancellationToken);
}

public sealed class Message
{
    public WebSocketMessageType MessageType { get; set; }
    public OwnedMemorySequence<byte> Payload { get; set; } = null!;
}

public sealed class OwnedMemorySequence<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CollectionDisposable _disposable = new();
    private readonly MemorySequence<T> _sequence = new();

    public ReadOnlySequence<T> ReadOnlySequence => _sequence.ReadOnlySequence;

    public OwnedMemorySequence<T> Append(IMemoryOwner<T> memoryOwner)
    {
        _disposable.Add(memoryOwner);
        _sequence.Append(memoryOwner.Memory);
        return this;
    }

    public ReadOnlySequence<T> CreateReadOnlySequence(int firstBufferStartIndex, int lastBufferEndIndex)
    {
        return _sequence.CreateReadOnlySequence(firstBufferStartIndex, lastBufferEndIndex);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposable.Dispose();
    }
}

public static class MemoryOwnerSliceExtensions
{
    public static IMemoryOwner<T> Slice<T>(this IMemoryOwner<T> owner, int start, int length)
    {
        if (start == 0 && length == owner.Memory.Length)
            return owner;
        return new SliceOwner<T>(owner, start, length);
    }

    public static IMemoryOwner<T> Slice<T>(this IMemoryOwner<T> owner, int start)
    {
        if (start == 0)
            return owner;
        return new SliceOwner<T>(owner, start);
    }

    private sealed class SliceOwner<T> : IMemoryOwner<T>
    {
        private readonly IMemoryOwner<T> _owner;

        public SliceOwner(IMemoryOwner<T> owner, int start, int length)
        {
            _owner = owner;
            Memory = _owner.Memory.Slice(start, length);
        }

        public SliceOwner(IMemoryOwner<T> owner, int start)
        {
            _owner = owner;
            Memory = _owner.Memory[start..];
        }

        public Memory<T> Memory { get; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _owner.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public sealed class MemorySequence<T>
{
    private MemorySegment? _head;
    private MemorySegment? _tail;

    public ReadOnlySequence<T> ReadOnlySequence => CreateReadOnlySequence(0, _tail?.Memory.Length ?? 0);

    public MemorySequence<T> Append(ReadOnlyMemory<T> buffer)
    {
        if (_tail == null)
            _head = _tail = new MemorySegment(buffer, 0);
        else
            _tail = _tail.Append(buffer);
        return this;
    }

    public ReadOnlySequence<T> CreateReadOnlySequence(int firstBufferStartIndex, int lastBufferEndIndex)
    {
        return _tail == null ? new ReadOnlySequence<T>(Array.Empty<T>()) : new ReadOnlySequence<T>(_head!, firstBufferStartIndex, _tail, lastBufferEndIndex);
    }

    private sealed class MemorySegment : ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>
    {
        public MemorySegment(ReadOnlyMemory<T> memory, long runningIndex)
        {
            Memory = memory;
            RunningIndex = runningIndex;
        }

        public MemorySegment Append(ReadOnlyMemory<T> nextMemory)
        {
            var next = new MemorySegment(nextMemory, RunningIndex + Memory.Length);
            Next = next;
            return next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to trim. You just need to slice your memory accordingly.

Pay attention to `MemoryPool<T>.Rent` ([quote from the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorypool-1.rent#returns)) returning "*[...] a memory block capable capable of holding **at least** minBufferSize elements of T.*" The important bit here is "***at least***", meaning the returned memory is allowed to be larger than the requested size.

All you need to do is to create a slice of the requested size from the memory if it happens to be larger than the requested size before adding it to *OwnedMemorySequence<T>_sequence* member .

Comment: So how do I do that?

Comment: Got it. `seq.Append(buffer.Slice(0, bytesCount));`.